# How do I add running and animations to my player controller script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am new to Unity and have been having a hard time adding running and animations (I have the animations and they are set up in animator) to my FPS controller script. Can someone please help me add running and animations? I would be extremely grateful.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
Animator anim;
float RotateX;
float RotateY;

public static bool GamePaused;
[SerializeField]
[Header("Game Objects")]
public GameObject Camera;
public GameObject PauseMenu;
public GameObject Player;

[Header("Movement Settings")]
public float WalkSpeed = 5.0f;
public float RunSpeed = 10.0f;

[Header("Rotation Settings")]
public float RorationSpeed;
public float MaxYAxis = 60.0f;       // right
public float MinYAxis = -48.0f;     // left

public bool Grounded;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
void Update()
{

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, 0f, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);

    }
}
```

Here is what I have to trigger the different animations in the animator, but the animation follows through when I release the key rather than switching immediately upon release.

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || 
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to be using the built-in physics system you should refrain from using transform.Translate.

Comment: @Eddge As I said I am new to this. All I really know is that I have made a working script.

Comment: I wouldn't have commented that if you didn't say you were new, my reason for commenting that is so you can look up other ways to move your character, those systems will give you the ability to calculate your characters speed which you can use to pass information over to the animation system =)

Comment: Sorry. not sure I follow.

Comment: Typically animation systems are based off of some form of state machine.  In Unity  you can create whats called an animation controller, and create triggers/conditions for transitioning between animations.  With your current layout you really dont have anything in place to send to that system, because you are directly moving your gameobject and not storing any data.  If you used a rigidbody, you could pass your velocity to your animation controller, and it would handle the transitions between your animations if you set it up correctly.

Comment: @Eddge I made an edit to the post for what I do for animations. I also included what the issue was. Also I do use a rigidbody.

Comment: If you are using a rigidbody then you should rely on that to move your character, not transform.translate.   you could change your `anim.SetBool` in the if statement to `anim.SetBool("IsWalking", rigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 0.0f)`  which would remove the need for your if statement

Comment: @Eddge  Is this right?                                                                                           if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            anim.SetBool("IsWalking", GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude > 0.0f);
        }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my working script with walking, running, jumping and animation triggers.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
Animator anim;
float RotateX;
float RotateY;
Rigidbody rb;
public static bool GamePaused;

public bool isGrounded;

[SerializeField]
[Header("Game Objects")]
public GameObject Camera;
public GameObject PauseMenu;
public GameObject Player;

[Header("Movement Settings")]
public float DefaultSpeed = 5.0f;
public float WalkSpeed = 5.0f;
public float RunSpeed = 10.0f;
public float jumpForce = 2.5f;
public Vector3 jump;

[Header("Rotation Settings")]
public float RorationSpeed = 3.0f;
public float MaxYAxis = 60.0f;
public float MinYAxis = -48.0f;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Update()
{
    Rotation();
    Movement();
    Bool();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
    {

        rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

void Rotation()
{
    RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RorationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, 0f, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
}

void Movement()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        WalkSpeed = RunSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        WalkSpeed = DefaultSpeed;
    }
}

void Bool()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingForward", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingLeft", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingBack", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingRight", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingForward", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingLeft", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingBack", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingRight", true);
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingForward", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingLeft", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingBack", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingRight", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingForward", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingLeft", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingBack", false);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        anim.SetBool("IsWalkingRight", false);
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay()
{
    isGrounded = true;
}
void OnCollisionExit()
{
    isGrounded = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Using this if i were to hold down W and S at the same it wouldnt move but it would be animating. the other answer is much better.

Answer (score 2):

What I can suggest is that you use the horizontal and vertical axes, rather than hard-coded key presses.

More specifically, first of all (if you have not already) in the animator window create an idle state and a walking animation state. You will need somehow to transition between the two states. To do that you will need to create a new bool parameter (let's name it "isWalking" as you did) and create a new condition between the idle and the walking state. For example, set to transition between "idle" to "walking" when *isWalking* is true and transition between "walking" to "idle" when *isWalking* is false.

Now in your PlayerController script in the update or fixed update you can add the following code

```
horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

//normalize vector so movement in two axis simultanesly is balanced.
moveDirection = (horizontalMovement * transform.right + verticalMovement * transform.forward).normalized;

/* based on your code although a rigid body solution or character controller would have been more robust */
transform.Translate(moveDirection * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

if (horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0)
{
    animator.setFloat("isWalking",true);
}
else
{
    animator.setFloat("isWalking",false);
}
```

However this solution is working is implemented based on the code you provided. If you want to switch in a more robust and easy to maintain script you can use this free controller that uses a rigidbody and has animations already installed and working.

https://github.com/PanMig/First-Person-Unity-Camera

Comment: Thanks I got it working though. I will post my script.

Comment: @EthanK-B if this solved your issue you should mark it the answer.

Comment: @Migko you probably already know this but you could just insert your if condition into your setFloat statement and it would do the same thing.