# Problem when pressing W and then A with W not working anymore UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a code for my animations and I wrote this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            animatorz.Play("SlowRun");
            Debug.Log("ya");
        }
```

Technically it all worked BUT when I press W and then, for example, A while pressing W I let go from A and it send me back to idle state but I was still pressing W, is there a way to make it properly like in actual games?
Thanks!

Comment: You should use `SetFloat` or `SetBool` on the animator to tell it whether or not you are moving, and set up the animation states to use that information properly. Does this answer your question? [How do I add running and animations to my player controller script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173131/how-do-i-add-running-and-animations-to-my-player-controller-script)

Comment: I tried doing that but it worked and not it was wierd and not at all correctly I did put the so like if this book true do this on the transitions lines in animator and in script and it was not good

Answer (score 0):

The `GetKeyDown` method only fires once. You want `GetKey` instead, which fires every frame: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Using this you'll want to check in the loop if the animation is already playing so you don't restart it every frame the player presses the key, use `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` e.g. https://answers.unity.com/questions/362629/how-can-i-check-if-an-animation-is-being-played-or.html

Comment: I write: if (Input.GetKey("w"))
But it doesnt detect it

Comment: nevermind it worlks but the A has 1 more animation and it doesnt play

Comment: well when i press W/a/d/s or wtvr the animation starts every second and u cant see it so what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This script will make it to where you can play the specified animation on the correct key press.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            animatorz.Play("W_Animation_Name");
            Debug.Log("W Animation");
        } //This will allow the animation to keep playing. 
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){

     animatorz.Play("A_Animation_name);
     Debug.Log("A Animation");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's not it I need it to be like this: I press W then A and when I stop pressing A W animations plays (A have a new animation )@Mintvbz

Comment: Well, the script makes it play the W animation whenever the W is pressed without the A being pressed. And it plays the A animation whenever both keys are pressed. What would you like me to change about it?

Comment: I mean see, whenever I press W it works when I press A but still hold W A plays which are good BUT whenever I release A even though W is pressed W doesn't play it's like A cancels it thanks.@Mintvbz